# Is there a replacement for the <v-app> tag of Vuetify?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer of Gabriel Tortomano, I replaced the root `<div>` tag with `<v-app` and started to look how to fix the css changes that came with `<v-app>`.

In the end it was not that hard. Just set the properties that you don't need that automatically come with `<v-app>` to `unset`.

```
.v-application {
    .title {
        font-size: unset !important;
        font-weight: unset !important;
        letter-spacing: unset !important;
    }

    a {
        color: unset !important;
    }
}
```

Because of this I could also remove the `id="app"` and `data-app`, because they are automatically included.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Within my application I am using Vuetify components. One of those components is the `<v-switch>`.

The problem that I am having is that I need to add the `<v-app>` tag to the root of my application to get the `<v-switch>` to work. The root of my application looks like this:

```
<div id="app" data-app>
    <component :is="layout">
        <router-view />
    </component>
    <portal-target name="dialog" multiple />
    <portal-target name="messagebox" multiple />
    <administration-selector :visible="selectorVisible" :administrations="administrations" @logout="logout" @use="setAdministration" />
</div>
```

I already added the `data-app` to the root `<div>` so that the `<v-select>` would work, but now it seems I really need to add the `<v-app>` tag.

When I replace the `<div id=.......>` to `<v-app id=......>` all of the current css is no longer applied to everything within the `<v-app>` tag.

Does anyone knows how to solve this or maybe a better solution then adding `<v-app>` to the root of the application?

(adding the `<v-app>` tag only around the `<v-switch>` also results in some weird css styling)

Comment: The next release off Vuetify (3.x) will not require `v-app` as the root component, so maybe you could switch to that beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right, sadly you'll probably be forced to rewrite some of your css. The correct way is to replace your div with < v-app > ; id is not needed, v-app already provides an id="app". Have made this mistake multiple times and had to rewrite some css to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

just wrap your div with `<v-app>` or either way

```
<v-app>
    <div id="app" data-app>
        <component :is="layout">
            <router-view />
        </component>
        <portal-target name="dialog" multiple />
        <portal-target name="messagebox" multiple />
        <administration-selector :visible="selectorVisible" :administrations="administrations" @logout="logout" @use="setAdministration" />
    </div>
</v-app>
```

Comment: This also results in the weird css changes